# Wrap part of a foreach loop in a div

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to wrap everything after the second item in a doc. Here's the code that doesn't work. It's being used in a Razor view.

```
@{var j = 0; var count = 10;}
@foreach (var reply in comment.CommentReply.OrderBy(x => x.DateCreated))
{

    if (j == 2 && count > 2) {
        <div class="hidden-replies">
    } 

    Html.RenderPartial("_Reply", reply);

    j++;
    if (j == count && count > 2) {
        </div>
    }

}
```

I believe it's still waiting for the closing div so the else doesn't get read. How do I fix this?

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you're going to end up with something that looks like this: <div class="hidden-replies"><div class="hidden-replies"><div class="hidden-replies"><div class="hidden-replies"></div> because you are only rendering the closing div on the 10th item. I think what you need to do render both the opening and closing tag in the same conditional block, instead of trying to close it all up in the end. Can you elaborate more on what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to prefix the half-tags with `@:` to prevent Razor from parsing the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the original question. Disregard the following:

Try something like this instead:

```
@{var j = 0; var count = 10;}
@foreach (var item in replies)
{    
    if(j <= 2)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("_Reply", item);
    }

    if (j == 3) {
        <div class="hidden-replies">
    }

    j++;

    if (j == count) {
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem was with the --  @:  -- needing to be placed before the html because it's an incomplete tag that razor can't understand so it keeps waiting for more HTML when you've already gone back to code. Thanks for pointing out the error in the code up top, I fixed it so that error is no longer there.

Comment: Ah, and that tweak to the code completely changed the meaning in my mind, and would have changed my answer. I'm going to see if I can get mine deleted to avoid confusion because it doesn't make sense against the modified question any more.